# Does an undefined symbol from a vtable imply an error between interface and implementation?

Tags: c++, c++11, interface

Does this kind of error implicate an error between an interface and its implementation?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "MyClass::ChangeManager::GetChanges(
       MyClass::ObjectId, 
       MyClass::IChangeManager::Changes&, 
       bool)"
  , referenced from:
  vtable for MyClass::ChangeManager in libMobileUtils.a(ChangeManager.o)
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say the virtual function `GetChanges()` is lacking a definition. And your interface reminds me of [Fizzbuzz Enterprise Edition](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition)

Comment: not my implemenation.  heh.

Answer (score 2):

No. That simply means that when the implementation emitted the vtable, it chose to place that function in it. It's just a plain old undefined function.

Comment: Thanks for that information. :)   Im rebuilding now, and just removing it.  I actually dont think i need it